# Binding context to generator functions this and passing argument

Tags: javascript, node.js, generator, koa

```
var convert = require('koa-convert');
var genbind = require('generator-bind');

function* myGen(i) {
    console.log(this.x, i);
}
myGen = genbind({x:666}, myGen);
convert(myGen)(9);
```

This echos `666 undefined`, i was expecting `666 9`, any ideas?

Comment: What does this have to do with *Java*? I've replaced the [tag:java] with [tag:javascript] for you.

Comment: not sure why the java tag?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Hehe, was too quick there. thanks for fixing it!